# Node.js serve as a backend server for frontend app

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to use Node.js run as a back-end server to serve front-end **socket.io** request.

The samples I found, seems can only run pages from Node.js server.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

The above js include is served by Node.js, how to include it if the front-end is a different application (e.g. PHP or static pages) ? Do I need to include all the dependent socket.io js libraries to make it work?

Comment: There are no dependent libraries AFAIK. Besides, you will have to use full URL for socket.io script ( unless you do some fancy proxying ), because Node.JS and PHP can't listen on the same port.

Comment: @freakish if I open socket.io.js, I can see code like: var client = require('socket.io-client'); this is not normal javascript code, there must be some library dependency.

Comment: That's a server-side script, you are looking at incorrect file. The URL: `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is redirected to the other file, which I can't find at the moment. But you can view it in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currrently running apache/php alongside node.js/socket.io
If this is what you're trying to do, you can do it by serving socket.io on a different port than what apache is serving on (assumed 80).

In node.js, initialize the socket.io listener on a port 8080 for example:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
```

I believe, by default, socket.io will also serve its static client side files conveniently for you, such that in you html, you can:

```
<script src="http://yourhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your server configuration. You may choose a path to Node.js backend that is not used by any other resource, and configure your web-server to serve everything else.

E.g. for Apache I used ProxyPass directive to enable connections to a local Node.js on a different port (to bypass local port restrictions), though may be not an option for your purposes:

```
ProxyPass /help/server/ http://localhost:8002/ connectiontimeout=1500ms
```

Comment: My question is: I want Node.js serve request from front-end app (PHP or static pages) socket.io request, and I don't know how to include the socket.io library properly, cause all examples I found run fron-end by Node.js